# animating a spritesheet using crafty.js

Tags: javascript, html5, crafty

this is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/ek6ub4u5/1/

i don't understand what i am missing it's been three days now working and trying to do the animation but i am stuck

```
 Crafty.sprite(128, "https://0.s3.envato.com/files/42440549/1_Ninja.jpg", {
               idle: [1, 0]
           });
```

i've loaded the spriteseet image and declare `idle`

```
 Crafty.c("animation", {
               init: function () {
                   this.requires("SpriteAnimation");
                   this.animate("run", 1, 1, 4);
                   this.bind("enterframe", function () {
                       if (!this.isPlaying("run")) {
                           this.animate("run", 20);
                       }
                   });
               }
           });
```

then i have declared the animation component and the `bindframe` function

```
var player = Crafty.e("2D,Canvas,idle, animation")
                        .attr({ x: 0, y: ch - 128, w: 128, h: 128 });
```

then i've declared the player ,but sadly the animation is not working .. can anyone tell me what i am missing please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here.  First, SpriteAnimation has changed.  You now need to define an animation reel.

```
//this.animate("run", 1, 1, 4);
this.reel("run", 1000, 1, 1, 4);
```

Second, names in javascript and Crafty are case sensitive.

```
//this.bind("enterframe", function () {
this.bind("EnterFrame", function () {
```

Third, I fixed a few small problems with your jsfiddle so it will run.  http://jsfiddle.net/hso6cmvp/